# What happens when a char is assigned a value too large to fit in a byte?

Tags: c, char, integer-overflow

Let's say I have a char pointer:

```
    char * cp;
    int val2 = 2;
    cp = &val2;
    *cp = 1234;
```

What will happen since the value 1234 is too large to fit in 1 byte? Will it just overflow and cause incorrect values to be stored, or will it somehow store the correct value across several bytes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `*cp = 1234;`, `*cp` refers to just one byte, the first (lowest-addressed) byte of `val2`.

In an assignment, the value of the right-hand side is converted to the type of the left side. So, 1234 will be converted to `char`.

There are two complications here. One, in most C implementations, 1234 is too big to fit into a `char`. (The C standard allows a `char` to be larger than eight bits, but this is rare in modern computers.) Two, `char` may be signed or unsigned.

If `char` is unsigned, then the conversion is well defined: 1234 is reduced modulo one more than the largest value of `char` (usually 255, so the reduction is modulo 256). In the usual case, 1234 will be reduced to 210, and this will be stored in the byte referred to by `*cp`.

If `char` is signed and 1234 does not fit in a `char`, then the conversion is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised. In many modern C implementations, the result of the conversion will be -46.

The byte that `cp` points to after `cp = &val2;` is the lowest-addressed byte of `val2`. It is not necessarily the least significant byte of `val2`. Some C implementations store integers with the least significant byte lowest in memory (*little endian*), and some C implementations store integers with the most significant byte lowest in memory (*big endian*). (There are even systems that do not store the bytes in order; they may be mixed up in memory.)

Most modern C implementations store integers in two’s complement form without padding, so, once you know whether the C implementation is big-endian or little-endian, you would know how changing one byte would affect the value of the `int`. However, the C standard still permits sign-and-magnitude or ones’ complement. It also permits padding bits in signed integers.

Finally, note that `char` is a special type which permits accessing parts of other objects in this way. If, for example, you used `short` instead of `char`, as in `short *sp = &val2; *sp = 0;`, it would be a violation of aliasing rules, and the behavior would be undefined.

Comment: @user3284549 A fine and complete answer.  Be sure to take time to understand it.