# Type conversion confusion in C

Tags: c, type-conversion, unsigned, signed

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c = 255;
    if (c > 128)
    {
        printf("This is unsigned number %d\n", c);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("This is signed number %d\n", c);
    }
}
```

What happens in this case when we initialize an signed char which have range from -127 to 128 with 255? It doesn't wrap around because it is undefined behavior, but what really happens?

I am getting -1 result, but how and why?

Comment: You are asking what happens in undefined behavior?  Seriously?

Comment: This is not undefined behavior, but implementation defined. So it depends on your compiler.

Comment: @JensGustedt is passing char to %d, ok?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava, yes, all narrow types are converted to `int` when passing to a `va_arg` function.

Comment: could be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667971/what-happens-when-a-char-is-assigned-a-value-too-large-to-fit-in-a-byte

Comment: This is not necessarily implementation-defined behavior, even. If `char` is an unsigned type, it would print 255 on all compilers.

Comment: Duplicate helps, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't well-defined behavior. The relevant part of the standard 6.3.1.3 §3:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented
>   in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
>   implementation-defined signal is raised.

This means that the result depends on the compiler. Probably, your compiler attempts some sort of wrap-around based on two's complement - that's the most common behavior. It is not undefined behavior.

Please note that the `char` type could be either signed or unsigned, that also depends on the compiler.