# How are expression values stored before they become assigned in C?

Tags: c, expression, variable-assignment, implicit-conversion

Beginner question here;
in C, when you assign a numerical value to a variable, the language makes it clear that the variable has a specific type, which can contain only a specific range of numerical values. If the value one assign to a variable is outside the range defined by its type, it will overflow. Example;

```c
char foo = 1000;
```

here `foo` is not expected to be equal to 1000. I suppose assignment involves the expression's value to be casted to the variable type, consequently, assignment would potentially modify the value of the expression depending on whether overflow occurs or not, which depends on the variable type and the expression's value. In more complex cases (not hardcoded values), I suppose that the value which will be stored in memory is not known before the assignment actually happen.

My question is; during code execution, how are the values of expressions stored before they are assigned?

Indeed, they have to be written on a certain number of bits, which gives them a minimum, a maximum, and a precision maximum in the case of floating point values.

As an application of this question; is it possible to write an expression involving a hardcoded number so big that it actually cannot be stored properly during execution? Imagine a hardcoded expression involving a number a little larger than the maximum possible value, divided by two, such that the expression would *theoretically* produce a representable number, but it doesn't.

Comment: `If the value one assign to a variable is outside the range defined by its type, it will overflow` No, it will be _converted_. And the language defines how a value is _converted_ from one type to another, and what happens when the value is not representable in destination type.

Comment: The line `char foo = 1000;` is not technically an assignment expression; it is a declaration with an initializer.

Comment: The compiler can assume signed integer overflow or other forms of undefined behaviour do not occur, so it just generate code that does anything, nothing, or something completely different. It's not that interesting to speculate about what the UB might be, if you ask me. Just be careful and write defined code and don't worry.

Comment: See [scalar_initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scalar_initialization) and [Conversion as if by assignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)

Comment: Some compilers will issue a warning at compile time if it detects an overflow involving conversions of constant expressions such as this. For example, GCC release 4.2 onwards will warn about this by default.

Comment: For the possible formats and limitations of integer literals, see [integer_constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant)

Comment: In this case `1000` probably *won't* be stored "during execution" but dealt with by the compiler.

Comment: @WeatherVane et al, I think you were a little quick to close this; the question isn't really about overflow in an assignment, it's about how expressions are stored in the compiled code: **My question is; during code execution, how are the values of expressions stored before they are assigned?** I don't think the answer in the suggested dupe addresses this.

Comment: @Caleb I have voted to reopen, unless a better dup can be found - the "close reason" can be edited to include several dup questions.

Comment: For anyone how is interested in the previous dupe nonetheless: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667971/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinarily, each expression in C, including a subexpression inside another expression, has a type. For identifiers, the type is declared. For constants or literals, the type is a consequence of the form and value of the constant or literal. For the results of operators, the type is determined by the types of the operands and rules for the operator.

For example, for integer constants, there is a table in C 2018 6.4.4.1 5. For decimal constants without a suffix (like `l` for `long`), it says the type is the first of `int`, `long int`, and `long long int` that can represent the value. The following paragraph also says that, if the value does not fit in any of those, it can fit in some extended integer type provided by the C implementation. It also says if the value cannot be represented by any type in its list, and it “has no type.” If a constant has no type, then the program violates the constraint in the constraints clause 6.4.4 2, which says “Each constant shall have a type…,” and the behavior is not defined by the C standard. When a program violates an constraint listed in a constraints clause, the compiler must produce a diagnostic message for this.

For many operators, the rules say that integer operands are promoted to a width of at least `int`. (There are some technicalities I am omitting here, but this is the primary effect of the integer promotions.) This means you cannot do arithmetic on **just** a `char` or `short` value where in a C implementation in which those types are narrower than an `int`. Further, for many operators with two operands, the operands are converted to some common type, generally the “bigger” type (although again there are some technicalities, which can be more troublesome due to conversions between signed and unsigned types).

All of these rules about types affect the **values** that will result from evaluating expressions. If you add some value of type *X* to some value of type *Y* and multiply by some value of type *Z*, the rules will be applied to determine what value results. But the rules do not say how the value must be represented while the program is working with the expression. A compiler may generate code that processes values in registers, that keeps some constants in immediate fields in instructions, that builds some constants on the fly during program execution, that does not contain actual instructions that perform the explicit operations because the compiler optimized the expression to a different form, and more. The C standard only requires that a value be represented in a certain way when it is stored in an object (memory reserved to hold a value, as with a definition of a variable). (And even that can be removed by optimization, as long as the program behaves the same way with regard to the observable effects as defined by the C standard.)

Answer (score 4):

> My question is; during code execution, how are the values of expressions stored before they are assigned?

Typically, they're stored as constants in the code, like this:

```
movb   $-0x18, -0x11(%rbp)
```

That `-0x18` is the constant -24 being stored into some memory location.

> I suppose assignment involves the expression's value to be casted to the variable type, consequently, assignment would potentially modify the value of the expression

Right. My compiler warns me: `Implicit conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from 1000 to -24`

> As an application of this question; is it possible to write an expression involving a hardcoded number so big that it actually cannot be stored properly during execution?

Compilers will often simplify constant expressions, so if you've got an expression involving a number that's small enough that the compiler can work with it, but too large to be stored into whatever type you're trying to use, then yes, the compiler will do the right thing. If I change your example to this:

```
char foo = 1000/8;
```

the the warning from my compiler goes away.

Comment: The compiler does not evaluate integer constants with infinite range though, so something like the following might not set `foo` to 100 as expected: `#define BIG 100000000` `char foo = 100 * BIG / BIG;`. (My compiler sets `foo` to 14 for that, although it does warn about the overflow.) But `char foo = 100 * (BIG / BIG);` will set `foo` to 100 as expected.